# Can someone explain what I need to do to places that redirect to "localhost" when deploying the backend of an app

Tags: express, frontend

For example I have a middleware in express.js like this

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true
}))
```

If I hosted the frontend on for example firebase, the localhost:3000 part would no longer work so what do I need to do?

Comment: Maybe check your `process.env.NODE_ENV` and if it's firebase, change origin to the URL of your API: `origin: "http://firebase-app-name.firebase.com"`

Comment: you could set an environment variable of your url, and consume it using dotenv library.